# Bluetooth is turned on but not working

Tags: bluetooth

I have recently install Ubuntu, however the Bluetooth does not turn on from the settings Gui, even when i turn it on, It says "Bluetooth is turned off".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1yWI.png) . I have tried everything, restarting, reinstalling drivers etc.. How to fix it ?